# Audio stops playing after loading my game from the main menu scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, menu, pause

When I pause the game, the audio pauses too, but I created a "go back to menu" button, it goes to the main menu but when I hit start again and the game starts running, my audio is dead, I can not hear anything.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class pausemenu : MonoBehaviour { public GameObject pauseMenu;

 public bool isPaused;
 
 void Start()
 {
     pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
     {
         if(isPaused)
         {
             ResumeGame();
         }
         else
         {
             PauseGame();
         }
     }
      
 }   
 
 
 public void PauseGame()
 {
     pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
     Time.timeScale = 0f;
     isPaused = true;
     AudioListener.pause = true;
 }
 
 public void ResumeGame()
 {
     pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
     Time.timeScale = 1f;
     isPaused = false;
     AudioListener.pause = false;
 }
  
 public void GoToMainMenu()
 {
     Time.timeScale = 1f;
     SceneManager.LoadScene("menu1");
 } 
 
 public void QuitTheGame()
 {
     Application.Quit();
 }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the PauseGame() function you are setting the       AudioListener.pause to true. So, in the GoToMainMenu() function set the AudioListener.pause to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you pause your game and call `PauseGame()` `AudioListener.pause` is set to `true`.

If you resume you correctly set `AudioListener.pause` to `false`.

However, if you stop your game (by going into some main menu) and start a new one (or the previous one) the static bool `AudioListener.pause` is still `false` because of your pause menu intervention.

Even if your starting setup results in `pausemenu.Start()` getting called when starting a new game, this will not affect `AudioListener.pause`. You have to explicitly call `pausemenu.ResumeGame()`.